# Determining version of zend framework installed on server

Tags: zend-framework, shared-libraries, shared-hosting

Is there a way to determe what version of zend framework is installed on a server/included in the app? The reason I'm asking is that I'm on a shared host and I would like to use a different version than that supplied by the host and I would like to be certain that the version I'm supplying is the one being utilized by my website.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The file `Zend/Version.php` contains the version info.

```
echo Zend_Version::VERSION;
```

Answer (score 1):

And for ZF2 the file `Zend/Version/Version.php` contains the info.

```
echo \Zend\Version\Version::VERSION;
```

Answer (score 0):

Too determine Latest version of the installed Zend Framework,just follow the following two steps

One, Navigate to your project 
for example: oPEN CMD and navigate to your project files installation
"cd /path/to/project/"

Two,Type "php composer show --installed" or "composer show --installed"
depending wit your system configuration

This will give an output of all packages installed on your system with zend being inclusive