# Zend Project Migration

Tags: zend-framework, migration, version, laminas

i have a Zend Framework project and i need to know which framework and version they use. also is that mandatory to migrate the project from Zend to laminas. having no idea to what to do.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can use search [to find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358742/determining-version-of-zend-framework-installed-on-server) most of answers. Read [this text and linked articles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask.

Comment: chec composer file. It should say which ZF version you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the current version in `Zend_Version::VERSION` constant (there will be the same, but namespaced for ZF2 and ZF3 I believe).

Also migration to laminas is not "mandatory". It's just that Zend Framework 1/2/3 is no longer maintained.

You can find community maintained forks for older versions (like [diablomedia/zendframework1](https://packagist.org/packages/diablomedia/zendframework1))

Answer (score 0):

You can find the version of the framework and plugins in composer.json file in the application folder